# What is the legal EL syntax for "${param.mode${cntr}}"

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I'm writing this:

```
<c:forEach var="cntr" begin="1" end="10">
 <c:set var="mycase" value="${param.mode${cntr}}" />
 <c:if test="${mycase != null}">
   <c:param name="mode${cntr}" value="${mycase}"/>
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

The result I want is for the redirect that sits outside of this to inherit the values of `param.mode1`, `param.mode2`, etc. as if I wrote:

```
  <c:if test="${param.mode1 != null}">
    <c:param name="mode1" value="${param.mode1}"/>
  </c:if>
  <c:if test="${param.mode2 != null}">
    <c:param name="mode2" value="${param.mode2}"/>
  </c:if>
  <c:if test="${param.mode3 != null}">
    <c:param name="mode3" value="${param.mode1}"/>
  </c:if>
  <c:if test="${param.mode4 != null}">
    <c:param name="mode4" value="${param.mode2}"/>
  </c:if>
  <c:if test="${param.mode5 != null}">
    <c:param name="mode5" value="${param.mode1}"/>
  </c:if>
  <c:if test="${param.mode6 != null}">
    <c:param name="mode6" value="${param.mode2}"/>
  </c:if>
```

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to set another variable with `mode${cntr}` and to get the associated value using brace notation wherein you can pass a dynamic key.

```
<c:forEach var="cntr" begin="1" end="10">
    <c:set var="mode" value="mode${cntr}" />
    <c:set var="mycase" value="${param[mode]}" />
    <c:if test="${mycase != null}">
        <c:param name="mode${cntr}" value="${mycase}"/>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: That isn't working on Tomcat6. ${param['mode1']} does work, but the variable version won't.

Comment: It should work. I am however not sure if `<c:param>` eats that. Try putting it outside. What exactly do you need it for? To what servlet version is your `web.xml` declared?

Comment: The task is to put up a redirector that translates some params and passes others unmolested. So, URL xxx.org:8080/?mode1=yes&mode2=no& mode6=maybe would be mangled into 'if mode1=yes then mode1=YEAH, pass all others as-is and passed through the redirect as xxx.org:8080/bob.jsp?mode1=YEAH&mode2=no&mode6=maybe

Comment: I created a local test case where I replaced `<c:param>` by just `${mycase}<br/>` to print it and it works fine on both Tomcat 6 with web.xml set to Servlet 2.5 and Tomcat 7 with web.xml set to Servlet 3.0. In both cases I was using JSTL 1.2. I would however replace `${mycase != null}` by `${not empty mycase}` to skip empty strings as well.

Comment: @BalusC - Works! Thanks for extracting me from yet another trip into syntax hell.

Comment: What was the root cause?

Comment: @BalusC - not sure. The 'winning' code is:
 <c:redirect url="./xxx/index.jsp" >
  <c:forEach var="cntr" begin="1" end="10">
    <c:set var="paramName" value="mode${cntr}" />
    <c:set var="paramInherit" value="${param[paramName]}" />
    <c:if test="${not empty paramInherit}">
      <c:param name="mode${cntr}" value="${paramInherit}"/>
    </c:if>
  </c:forEach>
</c:redirect>